# PubKeyHash datatype vs BuiltinByteString for serialising scripts

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program

In one of the utility function for serialising validator functions, we have

```
validator :: PubKeyHash -> Validator
```

and

```
saveVal :: PubKeyHash -> IO ()
```

I was able to compute the PubKeyHash for my test wallet, but within the `cabal repl`, I'm getting different script addresses when I serialise the contract with:

```
:set -XOverloadedStrings 
import PlutusTx
import PlutusTx.Builtins 
import Plutus.V1.Ledger.Crypto

saveVal (PubKeyHash ("f8493..." :: BuiltinByteString))
```

vs with

```
saveVal "f8493..."
```

I'm not sure why this is the case. How am I suppose to "give" the pubkeyhash to the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, that won't store the PubkeyHash as the literal ByteString you want. We can see that by trying:

```
ghci> PubKeyHash "f778997b5e0fcaec19b7580bc23d010d24de9eea16f0275b5e766046"
6637373839393762356530666361656331396237353830626332336430313064323464653965656131366630323735623565373636303436
```

One way round is to use [fromHex](https://input-output-hk.github.io/plutus/master/plutus-ledger-api/html/PlutusLedgerApi-V1-Bytes.html#v:fromHex). For example, define a function using it to convert its output to BuiltinByteString:

```
import PlutusLedgerApi.V1.Bytes qualified as P
import PlutusTx.Builtins qualified as BI

bytesFromHex :: BS.ByteString -> BI.BuiltinByteString
bytesFromHex = BI.toBuiltin . P.bytes . fromEither . P.fromHex
  where
    fromEither (Left e)  = error $ show e
    fromEither (Right b) = b
```

(note that `Plutus.V1.Ledger.Bytes` changed to `PlutusLedgerApi.V1.Bytes`)

Then use to produce PubKeyHash:

```
PubKeyHash (bytesFromHex "f778997b5e0fcaec19b7580bc23d010d24de9eea16f0275b5e766046")
f778997b5e0fcaec19b7580bc23d010d24de9eea16f0275b5e766046
```